# get settings in validator - typo3

Tags: typo3, flux, extbase

I have an extension with backend configuration options.I need  to validate a phone number in AddAction and UpdateAction.I can configure the phone number format in backend (say us phone number/indian phone number etc).How can i get the settings in validator?
   I have a custom validator to validate phone numbers.Here is my code

```
    <?php
    namespace vendor\Validation\Validator;

    class UsphonenumberValidator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator
    {   


         protected $supportedOptions = array(
               'pattern' => '/^([\(]{1}[0-9]{3}[\)]{1}[ ]{1}[0-9]{3}[\-]{1}[0-9]{4})$/'
          );


          public function isValid($property) { 
                $settings = $this->settings['phone'];
                $pattern = $this->supportedOptions['pattern'];
                $match = preg_match($pattern, $property);

                if ($match >= 1) {
                    return TRUE;
                } else {
                $this->addError('Phone number you are entered is not valid.', 1451318887);
                    return FALSE;
                }

    }
}
```

> $settings returns null

Comment: Where's your validation? You say you need the value for validation, but your code does not show any attempt of validation.

Comment: @pduersteler i updated my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In cases where the `extbase configuration` of your extension isn't implemented by default you should retrieve it yourself by using the `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager`.

Here is an example how you can obtain the settings of your extension:

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyExtName\Something;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;

class Something {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    static protected $extensionName = 'MyExtName';

    /**
     * @var null|array
     */
    protected $settings = NULL;

    /**
     * Gets the Settings
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getSettings() {
        if (is_null($this->settings)) {
            $this->settings = [];
            /* @var $objectManager \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager */
            $objectManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
            /* @var $configurationManager \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager */
            $configurationManager = $objectManager->get(ConfigurationManager::class);
            $this->settings = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(
                ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_SETTINGS,
                self::$extensionName
            );
        }
        return $this->settings;
    }

}
```

I recommend that you implement such functionality in general. So you could retrieve any configuration of any extension as a Service inside your extension or something similar to this.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for giving a solution